# Wordpress migration ended with 500 Error page on pages excluding homepage

Tags: migration, 500-internal-error

I migrated wordpress form my localhost to two different places:

1) Home localhost with same attributes, name of database, directory paths and database passwords

2) Hosting directory with different paths, database name, pwd and user name

Problem:

Original destination works fine with all settings and pages, but places 1 and 2 successfully load DB, images, texts and homepage. If you check differences on homepage on those three computers it will be exactly the same.

But.

when i use menu to go to another page it will gives me 500 - Internal Server Error. At first i thought it is problem with hosting, so they told me my wordpress is making extended amount of redirections.
I tried to migrate that same application to place 1. But with the same result as on hosting.
Admin, logging in to admin works fine everywhere, editing pages, posts and everything else in admin menu too. but when i need to show page from edit on places 1 and 2 it gives me the same error as I discribed.

Can somebody help me solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is far too localised for us to help without actually taking a look at your server (which we are unable to do, we're not devs for hire unfortunately).

Comment: Have to ask this - have you reset your permalinks?